# Using split function in contingency table

Tags: r, contingency-tables, subset

I am quite beginner in R and I want to do a task that I think is manageable but I am still figuring out how. I have a contingency table like this:

```
contingency.table=
         feature1.A   feature1.B  feature1.C  feature2.A   feature2.B ..
group1      12           13           2          4             54
group2      44           43           6          43            56
group3      2            45           32         53            65
```

features may vary on how many sub-units it has (either two or three) but each feature has a unified prefix (like 'feature1' and so on)

I want to print a sub-matrices of features that has the data for each feature.

So sub-matrix3 (for feature 3) will look like this:

```
          feature3.A   feature3.B
group1      12           13   
group2      44           43 
group3      2            45
```

An idea to implement (in the case of having fixed 3 sub-units) would be like

```
features = length(contingency.table)/3
i=1
while (i < features) {
  print(contingency.table[,i:(i+2)])
  i=i+3
}
```

So this while loop simply iterates through each 3 columns. But What to do if we may have 2 columns ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. In what sense do you mean "may have two columns"? Can you clarify?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming, yet it needs further clarification to be suitable for [SO].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't supply a readily reproducible example (which makes it harder to give you useful code), I'll use an example from an inbuilt data set (the code should work if you copypaste into R):

```
contab <- with(airquality,table(OzHi = Ozone > 80, Month))
contab
```

From which we see that `contab` contains a contingency table:

```
       Month
OzHi     5  6  7  8  9
  FALSE 25  9 20 19 27
  TRUE   1  0  6  7  2
```

Now two-way tables are also matrices:

```
 is.matrix(contab)
[1] TRUE
```

for which it's easy to select arbitrary subsets of columns. For example, this:

```
 contab[,c(2,5)]
```

prints the second and fifth columns:

```
       Month
OzHi    6  9
  FALSE 9 27
  TRUE  0  2
```

What's not clear from your question yet is what criteria you need to satisfy in order to select some unknown number of columns.

Please edit your question to clarify, and please add a properly reproducible, small example on which we might try to more fully answer your question.